# PIG Script to group and aggregate data

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a file with data similar to the below one

```
(1,11)
(1,111)
(2,22)
(2,222)
```

How do I generate the output below?

```
(1,11,111)
(2,22,222)
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BagToString() function will help for your use case.

Ref : http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/api/org/apache/pig/builtin/BagToString.html

**Input :**

```
1,11
1,111
2,22
2,222
```

**Pig Script :**

```
inp_data = LOAD 'input_data.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (id:long,value:long);
inp_grp_id = GROUP inp_data BY  id;
req_stats = FOREACH inp_grp_id GENERATE group AS id, BagToString(inp_data.value,',') AS values;
```

**Output :**

```
(1,11,111)
(2,22,222)
```